# Angular 2 Interpolation inside a inline CSS

Tags: angular

I need to provide a dynamic image link fetched from server.

```
<div *ngFor="let Feed of TopStories" style="background-image:url({{Feed.imageLink}}); background-size:cover;">
```

How it will work ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NgStyle` to dynamically assign css properties to your elements, like this:

`<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image:url('{{Feed.imageLink}}')}"></<div>`

Answer (score 0):

This one worked
[ngStyle]="{'background-image' : 'url(' + Feed.imageLink+ ')'}"

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can add a parent div `<div *ngFor="let Feed of TopStories"> <div style="background-image:url({{Feed.imageLink}}); background-size:cover;">`
This may not be the standard way but it will work